# Scala/Play thread pool metrics

Tags: scala, playframework

Is there any way to get thread pool metrics in Scala or Play Framework?

In *scala.concurrent* I can only access

```
ExecutionContextExecutor
```

which does not have the methods returning active connections, queued task count etc.

I cannot cast it the implementations which have access to the executor since they are private.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it that way:

```
val field: Field = Class.forName("scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl").getDeclaredField("executor")
field.setAccessible(true)
val executor: ForkJoinPool = field.get(ExecutionContext.global).asInstanceOf[ForkJoinPool]
```

I'm aware that it works only with *ForkJoinPool* at the moment but using some pattern matching, etc. it can be made more generic and work with *ThreadPoolExecutor* too.